Prove Steffensen's method converges quadratically
Steffensen's method is defined as $x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{g(x_n)}, g(x) = \frac{f(x+f(x)) - f(x)}{f(x)}$
Suppose the sequence converges to $x^{*}$, then to prove quadratic convergence it must be shown that $e_{n+1} = Ce_{n}^{2}$, with $e_i = x_i - x^{*}$.
My first thought was to re-write $\frac{f(x_n)}{g(x_n)} = \frac{f(x_n)^2}{f(x_n +f(x_n)) - f(x_n)}$, then use Taylor expansion to simplify until my right hand side is of the form $Ce_{n}^{2}$.
If this is the right idea, could someone explain how I would Taylor expand something like the denominator? I have only ever Taylor expanded functions with simple arguments. Or if Taylor expansion isn't the right approach, what could I try?

This question recurs frequently, for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897005/quadratic-convergence-of-a-specific-iteration-steffensens-method, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2699486/using-steffensens-method-trying-to-prove-phi-x-0. The general idea is that Newton-like method still converge quadratically if the derivative approximation is close enough to the derivative, and improving with the convergence of the sequence.
